# Open Firmware - RAM Size

Tags: macos, mac, bash, unix, shell

Is there a command to get the amount of RAM in Open Firmware mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on startup)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply boot into openfirmware and type:

```
dev /memory@() .properties
```

It will give you all information about the RAM.
Bank-sizes is the size of each module in hex.